# Pdfmake.js issue with mozilla browser(latest version)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, pdfmake

I have adopted the pdfmake.js library into my angular js project for generating PDF's.Its implemented well and works very fine with google chrome(all versions) and mozilla(only some versions).
In mozilla latest version (50.0.0),can't generate Pdf. and there is no error in the console. I have searched long time for the solution of this problem.
I couldn't find out and couldn't fix my self.
If any one encountered this problem and know the solution of this issue, please just share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

I was going through same issue. this is the issue is related with the version of  pdfmake you are usng.

Try [this](https://github.com/tsiegleauq/pdfmake) version.

It is more stable and performance wise its much more better.